# Сочетание animation и async/await

Tags: javascript, canvas, css-animation, async-await

Уже спрашивал что-то подобное, но вопрос был путаный.
На этот раз подготовил специальный простой пример, где проблема ясна.

Задача такова: нужно нечто нарисовать на канве, сделать появление-исчезновение, потом нарисовать новое, опять fade in - fade out и т.д.
Важно:

1. Все операции должны быть сделаны через `async/await`. Во-первых, это учебный проект, так надо.
   Во-вторых, в примере ниже в качестве рисования использована просто заливка.
   Но в проекте это будет сложная рандомная фигура, создание которой занимает неопределенное время.
2. Анимация должна идти через css - там больше встроенных возможностей. Но очень нежелательно использовать явное время через `setTimeout`.
   Поэтому мы ждем `onanimationend`

```js
const randomHsl = () => `hsla(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%, 1)`
const draw = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = randomHsl();
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    resolve('Done draw');
  });
}

const fadeInOut = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    cnv.classList.toggle('fader');
    cnv.onanimationend = () => {
      cnv.classList.remove('fader');
      resolve('Done fade');
    }
  });
}

async function animate() {
  while (isAnimate) {
    let info = await draw();
    console.log(info);
    info = await fadeInOut();
    console.log(info);
  }
}


let cnv = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
let isAnimate = true;
cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
animate();
```

```css
  .fader {
  animation-name: myFader;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

@keyframes myFader {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Почему основной цикл выполняется только один раз?? Все работает, onanimationend отлично возвращает промис, но второе переключение класса не запускает анимацию!
**UPD** В сниппете здесь цикл работает, как надо.
НО, в Мозилле с локального файла,и в Codepen - только один раз. Почему?! [Вот кодепен](https://codepen.io/dharma-cat/pen/poKgWEw).

**UPD2**
Даже если обернуть канву в div и делать анимацию этого дива, тоже самое. Игра toggle/remove/add с классами анимации также не помогает.

Comment: а так и задумывалось, скрытие именно элемента canvas, а не того, что на нем нарисовано?

Comment: перенес код в сниппет - вроде работает как ожидалось и не один раз?

Comment: @Grundy  А как скрывать нарисованное, а не канву через CSS? Может я туплю... Но это пока не принципиально.
Загадка в другом, см upd

Comment: нарисованное через css - никак нельзя скрывать.

Comment: забавно, если в сниппете убрать вывод в сниппетную консоль - ошибка воспроизводится

Comment: Да... Буду признателен, если вы еще немного посмотрите. Похоже это связано с особенностями браузеров, а я в этом не очень разбираюсь (

Comment: да, похоже связано с какими-то особенностями repaint/reflow браузера. Добавить после `info = await fadeInOut();` строчку `cnv.offsetHeight;`

Comment: позже постараюсь подробнее ответ написать

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: isAnimete is not defined` первая итерация цикла проскакивает до проверки. а местный сниппет судя по всему часть ошибок фиксит(уже далеко не раз такое было что тут все работает а в локальном файле нет)

Comment: @Grundy  Да, так работает! Но почему?? Ведь код в целом чистый, без особых извращений, все прям как в учебниках. Важно, чтобы не просто "работало", стараюсь тщательно изучить современный JS-CSS.
И жаль, что там все еще много "танцев с бубнами"

Comment: @lesobrod, не понял upd2

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что если использовать один универсальный css-class `.fader`, код в таком виде работает странно. Можно использовать совет из комментариев (добавить `cnv.offsetHeight;`), но для меня это загадка.
Сохранить сочетание `animation` и `async/await`, можно используя два класса:

```js
const randomHsl = () => `hsla(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%, 1)`
const draw = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
ctx.fillStyle = randomHsl();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
resolve('Done draw');
});
}

const fadeIn = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
cnv.classList.add('fadeIn');
cnv.onanimationend = () => {
  cnv.classList.remove('fadeIn');
  resolve('Done fadeIn');
    }
});
}

const fadeOut = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
cnv.classList.add('fadeOut');
cnv.onanimationend = () => {
  cnv.classList.remove('fadeOut');
  resolve('Done fadeOut');
    }
});
}

async function animate() {
draw();
  while (isAnimate) {
let info = await draw();
    info = await fadeIn();
    info = await fadeOut();
    
}
}

let cnv = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
let isAnimate = true;
cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
animate();
```

```css
 .fadeIn {
animation-name: myFadeIn;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;
animation-direction: forward;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.fadeOut {
animation-name: myFadeOut;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;
animation-direction: forward;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes myFadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
70% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes myFadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
30% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

body {
margin: 0%;
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```